# How to set and get the value of a global variable ?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set and get the value of a global variables. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexanderbulatovick/r8fsh3ek/)

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="setValue" onClick="setValue()">
<input type="button" value="getValue" onClick="getValue()">
```

JS

```
//setting global variable
var theValues = '';

function setValue() {
    theValues = "test";
    alert(theValues);
}

function getValue() {
    alert(theValues);
}
```

But it is not throwing an error and not working

Comment: What error? try window.theValue when calling global vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your jsFiddle setting to allow your code to truly be in the global namespace.  Right now, your code is in an onload handler and is thus not global and so the event handlers specified in your HTML are not found and thus never called.

In the upper left of your jsFiddle, change the drop-down that says `"onLoad"` to be `"No wrap - in head"`.  Then, your jsFiddle will work as it does here:http://jsfiddle.net/r8fsh3ek/2/.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
<input type="button" value="setValue" onClick="setValue()">
<input type="button" value="getValue" onClick="getValue()">
```

Your javascript code :-

```
var theValue= '';
 function setValue() {
   theValues = "test";
    alert(theValues);
     return theValues;
}

function getValue() {
    theValues = setValue();
    alert(theValues);
  }
```

Comment: What did you change and why? Why should returning the value make `setValue` work? And calling `setValue` inside `getValue` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: I have just given another way to set the variable.

Comment: What's the other way?

Comment: Things I have changed in the above code.

Comment: How does `return theValues;` set the variable? Either way, if you read the accepted the answer, you will see what the actual problem was. There was nothing wrong with the way the OP set the variables.